# Add to cart attribute validation for configurable products?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I have two attributes used on my configurable products.

I have seen other Magento sites that have a warning appear if you try to click the Add to cart button before selecting all attributes.  Is this standard Magento behaviour? If so why does mine not do it?

I am using 1.9 and if I do not choose the attributes (I am using swatches) and i click the Add to cart button, noting happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute must be required, then only magento standard behavior work, i.e prevent Add to card unless selected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have disabled swatches for now and I can see that it is showing "* Required Fields" next to the dropdown boxes. The attributes for the config products were not set to Required. I have done that now but still nothing happens when you click the Add to cart without choosing an option. I have gone back to the default template and tried the rwd template too and get nothing from either of those.